# Запуск программы после checkout в SVN

Tags: java, svn

Как запустить проект (программу) в *Eclipse*? Есть проект джава, я его через *SVN* сохранил на компьютер для последующего дебага. Но у меня не выходит его запустить. Run As... ---> Run Configurations --> Java Aplication --> далее не знаю что мне вводить. Кнопка Browse... выдает пустое окно, там ничего ввести нельзя, а через Search... ничего не ищет. Не пойму, что я делаю не так.

P.S. вверху слева есть ошибка, что Main тип не указан. Где го указать? (`Main` метод в программе есть)

[image: скриншот конфигурации]

Comment: Покажите структуру проекта.

Comment: @post_zeew  [Structure]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sh8TG.png